# Why/how did Captain America age?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame

We don't know the exact details, but at the end of *Avengers: Endgame* we see Captain America

> going back to return all the Infinity Stones to their time lines. After that, he chooses a specific point in time in which he can have a "normal" life with Peggy, thus, creating another branch in the flow of time. We know from other questions/answers that he found some other way to go back to the main time line, and have that conversation with Falcon.

However, when he

> returns to the main time line, he is old!

Why did that happen? Does he follow a regular process of aging as any other human being? Or did he find a way to extract the super serum injected to him in the 1940s?

Comment: Because he went back in the 70s and lived another 50 years until the present time in movie?

Comment: @Rebel-Scum but wouldn't the super serum stop aging on him as it did while he was "sleeping" in the ice for aprox. 70 years?

Comment: @KennyBarrera Pretty sure the ice kept him from aging for those 70 years, not the serum.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum: “Because he went back in the 70s and lived another 50 years” — judging by the car that drives by the house he's in, I suspect he went back to the 1940s or 50s and lived another 70-80 years. Although as he's apparently travelled back to his original reality, he might have travelled in time too, so maybe he lived 200 years. But I don't think we've ever been told that post-serum Steve ages differently in the MCU.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Christopher Markus dates Steve going back to 1948, see my answer.

Comment: He is alive even after turning 200 years old. Don't you think that's impressive?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Because the serum only slows down the ageing process

Steve was born in 1918 as mentioned by Zola in the below quote, I believe his birthdate is 4th of July and I *think* that is mentioned in *Captain America: The First Avenger* but I can't find reference to that now.

> **Dr. Arnim Zola:** Rogers, Steven. Born, 1918.
>
> <sub>*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*</sub>

He then goes into the ice in 1945 and is brought back in 2011 in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* when SHIELD finds him. This would put him at 93 physically but the ice stopped the ageing process so he is technically only 27.

Fast forward to the end of *Avengers: Endgame* and we are in the year 2023 where Steve would be 105 years old physically or 39. He then decides to go back in time and according to Christopher Markus he travels back to 1948.

> **Fandango: So people are asking... Does this mean an old Captain America was hanging out this whole time while another Captain America was saving the day?**
>
> Christopher Markus: That is our theory. We are not experts on time travel, but the Ancient One specifically states that when you take an Infinity Stone out of a timeline it creates a new timeline. So Steve going back and just being there would not create a new timeline. So I reject the "Steve is in an alternate reality" theory.
>
> I do believe that there is simply a period in world history from about '48 to now where there are two Steve Rogers. And anyway, for a large chunk of that one of them is frozen in ice. So it's not like they'd be running into each other.
>
> <sub>[Fandango, EXCLUSIVE INTERVIEW: THE 'AVENGERS ENDGAME' WRITERS BREAK DOWN THE BIGGEST MOMENTS IN THE MOVIE [SPOILERS!]](https://www.fandango.com/movie-news/exclusive-interview-the-avengers-endgame-writers-break-down-the-biggest-moments-in-the-movie-spoilers-753736)</sub>

Seeing as Markus also states Cap lived in the main timeline the whole time that would mean at the end of *Endgame* he would be 180 physically or 114. For a 114 year old he looks to be in remarkable shape, probably of someone in their 80's and so I think we can assume he just ages slower than the rest of us.

Comment: “We are not experts on time travel, but the Ancient One specifically states that when you take an Infinity Stone out of a timeline it creates a new timeline.” For goodness sake Markus. You wrote the damn thing! This is your job!

Comment: So does this mean that during the brief time in 2011 when Cap Prime goes back to steal Loki's staff, there are *three* Steve Rogers in that time?

Comment: And also, Cap Prime suffered twice from the effects of the snap.(Although the second time he knew everything would end "fine", he saw the people suffering twice.)

Comment: I think he looks more like 109 than 114. Since there were two Caps at the snap, and prime Cap survived, wouldn't that make it more likely than not that "old" Cap didn't survive the snap and returned 5 years later?  That would make him 109.

Comment: @TylerH, yes, it means there were three Steve Rogers.

Comment: @Rob "young" Cap would've had to have survived in order to continue on to become Cap Prime and do all the time traveling to begin with.

Comment: @TylerH - And now my brain hurts again.

Comment: Bruce Banner explained that you can't change your history when you go back in time - I reject the idea that there were two Caps living side-by-side, it breaks the rules set out by the movie. Was Cap Prime just ignoring everything as the world was going to hell? Are the events in "Agent Carter" just completely rewritten because now she's with Cap the whole time? But that's impossible, because going back in time can't change your history - Based on Bruce's rules alone, any major change to history creates a fork in time.

Comment: They cannot change anything they already experienced, their past is fixed. they can change things that will affect their future experiences such as old Captain America showing up after the time travel was done.

Comment: @nzifnab - Cap was in a completely different timeline, then jumped back over to the prime timeline when he reached the right date. We don't really know what he did while he was there, aside from getting himself a new shield and dancing with Peggy Carter.

Comment: @Valorum well that depends on who you ask, the writers and directors disagree.

Comment: The writers disagree with the directors about whether Steve went to a different timeline when he lived his life with Peggy Carter, but both interpretations create a situation where there were two Steves existing simultaneously.  When Cap from Endgame travels back to 1948, there is another Steve Rogers frozen under the Arctic ice since 1945 when Red Skull's plane went down.

Comment: If the writers are right and this is still the "main" timeline, then the frozen Steve Rogers is Cap's earlier self, who will be unfrozen in about 2011, become leader of the Avengers, fight Thanos in 2023, and time-travel back to 1948 to become his present self.  Presumably he needs to hide from his earlier self to avoid messing up his own future and creating a Back to the Future style paradox.  (But didn't Endgame say that Back to the Future's rules for time travel were "a bunch of bull*"?  Yes, it did, which is why I think the writers may be confused!)

Comment: If the directors are right, and this is an alternate branch of the timeline, then the frozen Steve Rogers still exists under the Arctic ice when the "main" universe's Cap arrives in 1948, but there is no requirement that he follow the same path as he did in the "main" universe.  Maybe he gets unfrozen in 1948.  Maybe he never gets unfrozen.  Maybe he defeats Thanos the same way we saw in Endgame, or maybe he wakes up to find out that Old Cap has already taken care of Thanos for him.  We'll almost certainly never know-- I just hope *somebody* stops that timeline's Thanos.

Comment: @NathanK.that timeline Thanos is killed in our timeline at the end or Endgame. They are fine

Comment: @JohnMeacham I agree they cannot change anything in their own past - but that means NOBODY in this timeline can have had their past changed. If the writers are right, then the gas station attendant that old cap met last weekend won’t remember him, even though he remembers her. And if old cap, for instance, killed a robber a year ago - that robber will be alive and won’t have remembered it and old cap would be very confused if they met up. NOBODY that is alive that has interacted with old cap can have remembered him because of the rules that back to the future style paradoxes are impossible

Comment: @NathanK the directors are the ones with the plausible explanation; that old cap jumped parallel timelines after  living his life in his forked timeline with Peggy. The writers’ explanation leaves far too many holes and is inconsistent with the rest of the movie

Comment: There definitely were two Caps - a "Roger Stevens" was present at Peggy's funeral: https://comicbook.com/marvel/news/avengers-endgame-writers-always-two-captain-americas-steve-rogers-in-mcu-time-travel/

Comment: @TheFallen according to the writers yes, the directors would disagree.

Comment: @TylerH At some point post-Endgame Cap goes back to _return_ the Time Stone to the timeline too, so at that point, there are in fact 4 Captain Americas: Retired Cap, Helmet Cap, America's Ass Cap and Diligent Library Returns Cap.

Comment: @Möoz I don't remember Diligent Library Returns Cap?

Comment: @TylerH He's that good he's returning [a case full of books](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-fec18e30ab94bff620e9781b7d734728).

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Oh right. So he's there returning the stones when his future self (cap Prime) is there living out his life, while Endgame Cap is there fighting OG Cap. Phew. Actually, I think he would return *right after* Endgame Cap left the fight with OG Cap. He would have to return the staff somewhere where HYDRA would find it before OG Cap did when he woke up after being knocked out. So, that's a *maybe* on 4 Caps at once, IMHO.

Comment: @TylerH Aye, it isn't explicit if the 4 are there or not, there's anywhere between 1 and 4 at any one time in 2012. I've written about that a bit more [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/235329/58193) but be warned: word vomit.

Answer (score 3):

In *Captain America: The First Avenger* we learned that he can't get drunk due to the fact that with the Super Soldier Serum, his metabolism is increased 4 times and that the Serum is attached to his DNA cells, it prevents his cells from deteriorating as said by him,

> Steve Rogers: Dr. Erskine said that the serum wouldn't just effect my muscles, it would effect my cells. Create a protective system of regeneration and healing. Which means, um, I can't get drunk. Did you know that?
>
> Peggy Carter: Your metabolism burns four times faster than the average person. He thought it could be one of the side effects.

So with a lot of thought on my behalf I do not fully understand why he aged in *Avengers: Endgame*.

But another theory that I think is possible is that since he was in the ice for nearly 70 years, his cells were,like him, "frozen in time". And then when he came out of the ice, his cells very slowly started to degenerate but did not make a huge physical appearance.

But when he went back to return the Stones and made the decision to stay with Peggy (in around the 1940's), he did not have to crash the plane into the Atlantic and he went on that date with Peggy, so his cells continued to very slowly degenerate which allowed him to age around 106 years once he returns to the original timeline, in 2023 after defeating Thanos.

Comment: Your last paragraph is assuming that he somehow magically melded with the young Steve Rogers, which is implausible.