# How old is Captain America at the end of "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, avengers-endgame

We know that Captain America was born in 1918. However, his serum slows down his aging process. My question is, how old exactly is Captain America at the end of *Avengers: Endgame*,

> after he comes back as an old man?

Comment: “his serum slows down his aging process” — does it, in the movies?

Comment: [Very related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212100/58193).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Since him being defrosted 12 years ago, he looks almost identical now.

Comment: @Redline: Paul Rudd was in the last season of Friends 15 years ago, and he looks almost identical now too. The only serum stopping Cap from visibly ageing is diligently-applied moisturiser!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite lol. But is it not common belief, based on the comics, that the serum slows down his aging process? Even when Cap comes back as an old man, he does not look like his is 114. He looks in his late 80s at the most.

Comment: @Redline: oh, well if it's a common belief, then it must be true. If it's not in the movie, it's not in the movie. His appearance as a 114 year old man is the best case for some serum-assisted reduced aging, but I'm not sure how reliably distinguishable late-80s is from mid-hundred-teens. [Here's a 112 year old man](https://uk.news.yahoo.com/worlds-oldest-man-yasutaro-koide-dies-at-age-112-150749235.html).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Chronological time

Captain America was born July 4, 1918. The events of Endgame take place in 2023.
He then time-jumped from 2023 back to [1948](https://movieweb.com/avengers-endgame-directors-writers-time-travel-argument/) and lived his life until ending up back in 2023.

**In *cumulative* time, this makes him approximately 180 years old at the end of Endgame.**

---

### Unfrozen time.

Captain America was frozen in the year 1945 aged 27. He was defrosted in the year 2011 and lived until 2023, then looped back around to 1948. He then lived (unfrozen) until 2023.

**His cumulative *unfrozen* time is approximately 114 years.**

Comment: I believe a comment from the writers was that he went back to 1948. That would fit in with the established timeline since Season 1 of *Agent Carter* was in 1946, and Season 2 in 1947, thus there's no change in what was seen in that series, where she believed Steve had died in 1945 and had several potential romantic partners.

Comment: @KeithMorrison - https://movieweb.com/avengers-endgame-directors-writers-time-travel-argument/ - **'48**

Comment: So, he is set to die in a couple years?

Comment: @Redline: who are we, Doctor Strange? We don't know!

Comment: If you want a better write up of this, in my completely unbiased opinion, see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212100/58193).

Comment: @KeithMorrison but since MCU now has time travel and alternative timelines, there's no telling what Agent Carter that was.

Comment: @PaulDraper: which, coincidentally, was Steve's excuse when that kiss with Peggy's grand-niece came up.

Comment: I can't agree with this because we don't know whether the mechanism for getting back from the alternate timeline back to the primary one involved additional time travel.   And there's a pretty good reason to suspect it did.    At the very least, we could posit he may have stayed in that timeline until his wife died and then traveled back.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Sure. There are a lot of what-ifs and I'll keep updating it as and when any new info comes out.

Comment: +1 This answer *really* shines for the frozen and unfrozen vs unfrozen only time.

Answer (score 3):

I have a theory. We know that Peggy Carter dies in 2016, as seen in the MCU. At that point, I think that Captain America decides to return to the original timeline some time before he leaves, so that he can be on the bench. This gets rid of the discontinuity between timelines, and stuff like that. It also makes him 7 years younger than most estimates, as well as having him skip the Snapture. This means that unlike most answers say, he is actually 107. Added on to this the serum, and he is probably in his biological mid 80's. While the theory is my own, it also makes sense, as he knew that Peggy would die in 2016, and probably wanted to avoid the Snapture.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to say here. Are you saying he lived normally until Peggy's death in 2016, then jumped forwards in time to 2023? Is there any evidence to support that?

Comment: Yes, I am saying this. While it's speculation, it does make sense. The main reason he went back was to live with Peggy, once she died he had to get back to the main timeline. In the movie it says that what you do in the past doesn't affect the present, meaning that if he tried to go to the past and then use the normal passage of time to bring himself forward it wouldn't work. Once Peggy was gone there was no reason for him to stay. The evidence is that he was on the bench, meaning he had to travel back with Pym particles. Time travel in end game doesn't work like Back to the future, he had to

Comment: go from the other timeline to the normal one.

Comment: When you put it like that, it makes more sense.